# jquery json php html does not show results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to use Jquery with json and returning the results by replacing a DIV with the class alert. also i know js uses alert to so im gonna change that later.
But im kinda stuck here, it does post to the seconds file (offerte2.php) but doesnt show any results.
I'm not sure if its a java or php fault. anybody has some ideas?

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $('#form');
var submit = $('#submit1');
var page1 = $('.page1');

form.on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: '******/shop/templates/Euphoria-Art/offerte2.php', // form action url
  type: 'post', // form submit method get/post
  dataType: 'json', // request type html/json/xml
  data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
  beforeSend: function() {
    page1.fadeOut();
  },
success: function(result) {
    if(result.error){
        page1.html(result.html).fadeIn();
        console.log(e)
    }else{
        page1.html(result.html).fadeIn();
        form.trigger('reset');   
    }
}

});
});
});
```

to capture the values

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){            
$class1 = filter_var($_POST['class1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$class2 = filter_var($_POST['class2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$class3 = filter_var($_POST['class3'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$class4 = filter_var($_POST['class4'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$class5 = filter_var($_POST['class5'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$result = array("error" => false, "html" => null);
$totaal1 = $class1 + $class2 + $class3 + $class4 + $class5 

$result["error"] = false;
$result["html"] = "<h3>Het totaal is .$totaal1.</h3>";
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: please reduce the code in your question to the minimum. this helps us to look for mistakes and it helps you to localize the error.

Comment: ok.. wait.. html can be deleted

Comment: what do you get, when you just alert() or console.log() your result inside the ajax success function?

Comment: Try putting this at top of your php header("Content-type: application/json");

Comment: @nothkildonan, i really do not know... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All seems fine unless that you missed a semicolon after `$class5`

```
$totaal1 = $class1 + $class2 + $class3 + $class4 + $class5;


if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){            
    $class1 = filter_var($_POST['class1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $class2 = filter_var($_POST['class2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $class3 = filter_var($_POST['class3'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $class4 = filter_var($_POST['class4'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $class5 = filter_var($_POST['class5'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $result = array("error" => false, "html" => null);
    $totaal1 = $class1 + $class2 + $class3 + $class4 + $class5;

    $result["error"] = false;
    $result["html"] = "<h3>Het totaal is .$totaal1.</h3>";
} else {
    $result["error"] = true;
    $result["html"] = "<h3>Error</h3>";
}
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

Comment: nothing shows up, i think it maybe the javascript. i don't know IF this script can see the current url so i post the data to http://.....nl/whatever/anothersub/again/thereitis.php try it @ http://oostpijl.nl/shop/?nl_offerte1,68

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.oostpijl.nl/shop/templates/Euphoria-Art/offerte2.php. Origin http://oostpijl.nl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: wait i got it. removed the www.